# Avoiding SQL Injections with Parameters?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, parameters

I have recently adjusted my code to avoid getting SQL injections and got helped with adding parameters but now the code is semi-foreign to me and was wondering what object reference is required for MySqlCommand.Parameters

```
MySqlParameter parameter = new MySqlParameter();
        parameter.ParameterName = "@userid";
        parameter.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.NVarChar;
        parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameter.Value = this.userid_txt.Text;
        parameter.Value = this.email_txt.Text;
        parameter.Value = this.passone_txt.Text;
        parameter.Value = this.passtwo_txt.Text;
        parameter.Value = this.lastname_txt.Text;
        parameter.Value = this.firstname_txt.Text;

        string Query = "insert into userdatabase.users (userid, email, passone, passtwo, lastname, firstname) values(@userid,@email,@passone,@passtwo,@lastname_txt,@firstname)";
        MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", this.userid_txt.Text);
        MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", this.email_txt.Text);
        MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passone", this.passone_txt.Text);
        MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passtwo", this.passtwo_txt.Text);
        MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", this.lastname_txt.Text);
        MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", this.firstname_txt.Text);

        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection();
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The errors I have state

> 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType' does not contain a defintion for 'NVarChar'

and the main

> An object refrence is required for non-static field, method or property 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.Parameters.get'

I am relatively new to using MySql so any help is appreciated

EDIT: New code which causes a fatal error once I click register which connects to my database

```
MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand();
        MySqlParameter parameter = new MySqlParameter();

        string constring = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=welcome";
        string Query = "insert into userdatabase.users (userid, email, passone, passtwo, lastname, firstname) values(@userid,@email,@passone,@passtwo,@lastname_txt,@firstname)";
        cmdDataBase.Parameters.Add("@userid", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userid_txt.Text;
        cmdDataBase.Parameters.Add("@email", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = email_txt.Text;
        cmdDataBase.Parameters.Add("@passone", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passone_txt.Text;
        cmdDataBase.Parameters.Add("@passtwo", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passtwo_txt.Text;
        cmdDataBase.Parameters.Add("@lastname", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lastname_txt.Text;
        cmdDataBase.Parameters.Add("@firstname", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = firstname_txt.Text;


        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);

        try {
            conDataBase.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome to iDSTEM!");
        }
            catch (Exception ex)
        {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: You try to add parameters to your command before you created it? And your first 11 line is useless.

Comment: This is not MYSql errors, these are just normal .NET/C# errors. As the errors say, there's no enum value NVarChar value in MySqlDbType, so check what that enum contains. Additionally, you need to *construct* a command object before settings parameters, like you've done almost at the bottom. You need to construct `cmd` first, then instead of `MySqlCommand.Something` you write `cmd.Something`.

Comment: The code at the top does nothing useful and can be removed. It is only the `AddWithValue` that are needed.

Comment: The line `MySqlParameter parameter = new MySqlParameter();` is not needed nor used so you can delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You need the command itself - you're building it later:

```
MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
```

Just move that higher, and then use:

```
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue(...);
```

It's not clear why you're creating the `parameter` variable at all, as you're never using it.

I would actually not use `AddWithValue`, but instead use:

```
cmdDataBase.Parameters.Add("@userid", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userid_txt.Text;
// etc
```

MySQL doesn't have a type of `NVarChar`, so `MySqlDbType` doesn't either, hence your error - I strongly suspect you just want `VarChar`. You don't need to specify the direction - that's implicitly "input" by default.

Additionally, you should be using `using` statements for your connection and command:

```
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(...))
{
    using (var command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This was a lot of help, love seeing no red after good advice trying out everything now

Comment: Out of curiosity, Jon...what's the argument against `AddWithValue`?  An inherent coalesce issue is what you are suggesting?

Comment: @DonBoitnott: `AddWithValue` doesn't let you specify the parameter type explicitly; I prefer doing so to show exactly what I'm intending.

Comment: Your advice allowed me to execute and then got fatal error occurred once I clicked to enter information into the database

Comment: Well without knowing anything about that fatal error, it's hard to help you fix it...

Comment: I am trying to locate where things go wrong currently