# c# mysqlcommnand insert into mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, database-connection

i have a program that insert a list of field into the database. When i use my own computer to insert the datetime field it looks completing fine. however, when i insert it using a windows 7 chinese edition, the field become 0000-00-00 00:00:00
this is the command

```
MySqlCommand myCommand4 = new MySqlCommand("Insert into OrderRecords_table values('" + OrderIDLabel.Text + "','" + customerCode + "','" + customer + "','" + TelComboBox.Text + "','" + LicenseComboBox.Text + "','" +
                      DriverComboBox.Text + "','" + AddressComboBox.Text + "','" + LocationTypeComboBox.Text + "','" + PickupComboBox.Text + "','" + CustomerTypeLabel.Text + "','" +
                      Convert.ToDecimal(TotalPriceLabel.Text) + "','" + status + "','" + note + "','" + sandReceiptNo + "','" + createtiming + "','" + Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")) + "')", myConnection);
myCommand4.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

i know it looks a bit messy, but the part where it says
 `STR_TO_DATE('" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "','%Y/%M/%d /%H/%m/%s'))"`
is the part where i insert the current datetime. it works just fine when i use english version of windows, but whenever i use chinese edition, it isnert 0000-00-00 00:00:00 instead of the actual time, i have tried to change the format for showing dates in control panel, but it is still having the same problem.

anyone knows what the problem would be ?

Thanks

edited my code

```
var sql = "insert into OrderRecords_table values(@OrderID, @customercode, @customer, @PhoneNumber, @license, @driver, @address, @type, @pickupLocation, @PaymentMethod, @totalPrice, @status, @notes, @sandreceiptNo,@createTime, @EditTime)";

            using (var myCommand4 = new MySqlCommand(sql, myConnection))
            {        
                       myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderId", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = OrderIDLabel.Text;
                myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customercode", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  customerCode;
                myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer",MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = customer;
                myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value =TelComboBox.Text;
                myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@license", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LicenseComboBox.Text;
                myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@driver", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DriverComboBox.Text;
                myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = AddressComboBox.Text;
                myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LocationTypeComboBox.Text;
                myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pickupLocation", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = PickupComboBox.Text;
                myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PaymentMethod", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CustomerTypeLabel.Text;
                myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalPrice", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(TotalPriceLabel.Text);
                myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = status;
                myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notes",  MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value =status;
                myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sandreceiptNo", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sandReceiptNo;
                myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@createTiming", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = createtiming;
                myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EditTime", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
                myCommand4.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

its saying that i have some invalid input, but i have checked a few times that all the fields are asigned to the correct type.. . don't know what is happening

Comment: It does not only look messy, it is also open for sql-injection. Use sql parameters. That also fixes this localization issue as a sideline.

Comment: Change your statement to use @Parameters, then you will have no problems with different culture settings, and as second benefit: you´ll have no problems with user Input containing ' .. SQL injection ...

Comment: Please don't concatenate strings to generate SQL statements! Using a parameterized query is easier, faster and safer. You also *don't* have to concern yourself with conversions or cultures - just pass dates as date parameters, decimals as decimal parameters.

Comment: thank you all for the quick replies, however i dun quite get the meaning of using the parameters, is it possible to show me some examples? this is my first time using mysqlconnection, and i just started working with database recently @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Google for any tutorial on ADO.NET and parameterized queries, eg [Configuring Parameters and Parameter Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @benjiWong I also found the [following question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23390645/avoiding-sql-injections-with-parameters) here on SO regarding MySQL parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten your code to a more standardized implementation (with best practices). Note that I've pulled your query out into a separate variable to let the code and query become more readable.

```
var sql = "insert into orderrecords_table values " +
          "(@orderId,                            " +
          " @customercode,                       " +
          " @customer,                           " +
          " @telephone,                          " +
          " @license,                            " +
          " @driver,                             " +
          " @address                             " +
          " @locationType,                       " +
          " @pickup,                             " +
          " @customerType,                       " +
          " @totalPrice,                         " +
          " @status,                             " +
          " @note,                               " +
          " @sandreceiptNo,                      " +
          " @createTiming,                       " +
          " @currentTime)                        ";

using (var myCommand4 = new MySqlComm## Heading ##and(sql, connection))
{
   myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderId", OrderIDLabel.Text) ;
   myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customercode", customerCode);
   myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer", customer);
   myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telephone", TelComboBox.Text);
   myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@license", LicenseComboBox.Text);
   myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@driver", DriverComboBox.Text);
   myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", AddressComboBox.Text);
   myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locationType", LocationTypeComboBox.Text);
   myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pickup", PickupComboBox.Text);
   myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerType", CustomerTypeLabel.Text);
   myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalPrice", Convert.ToDecimal(TotalPriceLabel.Text));
   myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
   myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@note", status);
   myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sandreceiptNo", sandReceiptNo);
   myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@createTiming", createtiming);
   myCommand4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentTime", DateTime.Now);

   myCommand4.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: for those ?orderID, ?driver and such, am i suppose to put the "?" there? or you just saying that you are not sure about the column name?

Comment: @benjiWong Sql parameters begin with a token (usually `@`, but MySQL uses `?`). So you need to include the `?` prefix at the beginning of the parameter. You should review [MSDN Commands and Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254953(v=vs.110).aspx). It's very helpful. Keep in mind that most of the information is tightly coupled to Sql Server, but the concepts will be the same for MySQL.

Comment: i tried the code you provided with and without "?", if i do it without "?", it would run the code no problem, but the values on database would either be null or "", when i insert the "?", i get this error fatal error encountered during command execution.

Comment: Hmm... In that case replace the `?` with a `@` in the query itself and the `AddWithValue()` functions. All the references I found suggest that `?` is used rather than `@`.

Comment: according to this answer [fatal error](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/653480/Fatal-error-encountered-during-command-execution) it says it is because it is being execute for too long, do u know how i can set the execute time?

Comment: @benjiWong Do you have the exception message?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Additional information: Fatal error encountered during command execution.

Answer (score -1):

```
MySqlCommand Insert = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO [TABLE] ([Date], [TEXT]) VALUES(@Date, @Text) ", myConnection);
Insert.CommandTimeout = 60; //if you need
Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now);
Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Text", "Hello word!");
Insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
Insert.Dispose();
```

Comment: I downvoted your answer because of the following reasons: a "code-only" answer, and poor coding practices (using an object that inherits from IDisposable without a using construct).